# Selecting WIndows 10 as default boot option from HDD

Tags: hard-drive, boot, partitioning, bios

I have windows 10 on an old hdd on partition sda4. I installed another copy of windows 10 on an ssd and chose that as the default boot option; I no longer have that ssd and need to boot from the old hdd. I get 'No bootable devices' when selecting my hdd in bios menu. I am running ubuntu from a usb and I can view the partitions here. System: Alienware X51 R2

```
root@ubuntu:~# sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
NAME   FSTYPE     SIZE MOUNTPOINT                    LABEL
loop0  squashfs   1.8G /rofs                         
loop1  squashfs    91M /snap/core/6350               
loop2  squashfs  34.6M /snap/gtk-common-themes/818   
loop3  squashfs 140.7M /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74      
loop4  squashfs   2.3M /snap/gnome-calculator/260    
loop5  squashfs    13M /snap/gnome-characters/139    
loop6  squashfs  14.5M /snap/gnome-logs/45           
loop7  squashfs   3.7M /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57 
sda             931.5G                               
├─sda1 vfat        40M                               DIAGS
├─sda2            128M                               
├─sda3 ntfs      10.2G                               RECOVERY
├─sda4 ntfs       644G                               HDD
├─sda5 vfat       512M /target/boot/efi              
├─sda6 swap       7.9G                               
├─sda7 ntfs       450M                               
└─sda8 ext4     267.8G /target                       
sdb               7.4G                               
└─sdb1 vfat       7.4G /cdrom                        UBUNTU 18_0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment and I'm not very sure it will work for you. But given that no one is answering, here's my suggestion.

1. boot from a windows cd/dvd where you can use a command prompt.
2. type command `bcdboot C:\windows /s C:` and it should fix it.

This is under the assumption that the system you want to boot into is on drive c.

`BCDBoot` copies a small set of boot-environment files from the installed Windows image to the system partition [source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcdboot-command-line-options-techref-di)